# 143 lookup tables in EF CORE

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, lookup-tables

Currently I'm redesigning an existing program which uses a master table which contains multiple values. (C# .net core 3.0 & EF) (One big lookup table)

Much of these values are rarely changing and I would put them in a c# enum.

Some examples: Language, Sex, ReceiptStatus, RiskType, RelationType, SignatureStatus, CommunicationType, PartKind, LegalStatute, ...
The list goes on and on and currently has 143 different categories, each having their own values with 2 translations in it.

My company wants the values to be in the database, so a non programmer can change them when they have to.

However it doesn't feel good at all. I would love to separate the table but creating 143 tables seem a bit of an overkill. If it was only 5-10 lookup tables it would have been fine..

Any advice? Stick to 1 lookup table? Feels wrong to my eyes. Multiple tables?

Convince my company we should just use C# enums which work perfectly fine, ruling out the possibility that a non programmer can edit them?

Comment: We've been using Brian's 3rd way. In 3 years of development, no one ever tried to change any of lookups other than developers and most of the cases we needed to change code also. It complicates the version controlling since some of your enums stored in the db. but it seems its the best practise

Comment: @ilkerkaran I see. But adding 143 tables seem like a nightmare. Would it be an idea to find all the fixed value that we are sure are not going to change ever and put those in c# enums and the rest as separate lookup tables?

Comment: I would personally go with the first approach. I like to keep db as storage without any business knowledge.

Comment: So is my experience on previous projects I did. It rarely happened. They are a few tables that get updated regularly but those are a minority.

Comment: And henceforth in the lore of software engineering, the decision of using a table for every complete set of values shall be known as Brian's Third Way.

Comment: @BurnsBA, well played, but it is too late to edit my comment. Happy coding!

Comment: @Jesse Curious why it's such a nightmare BTW, versus the work you will have to do anyway? Is it just the drudgery of actually creating the tables and indexes and then having to look at them?

Comment: @BurnsBA I humbly accept my place in the lore :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your inclination to use enums, I'm going to assume that these lookup values do not change often.

Buckle up because a lot of hard-fought knowledge about maintainability is embedded in the analysis below. Let me break down the approaches you are considering:

1. **Pure enums:** This is the least flexible approach because it closes a lot of doors. As you said, changing values requires a developer and a deployment. What's your strategy if you eventually have other tables that need to relate to one of your many, many values? To me this is far too restrictive, especially since with either of  the other approaches, you could create a .t4 template that generates
   enums based on the data. Then if the data changes, you just
   re-generate. I do this a lot.
2. **One giant lookup table:** Not as flexible as it may seem! This trades complexity, single responsibility principal, and referential integrity against repetition/table spam and is probably an expression of the Big Ball of Mud anti-pattern. You could add a column to this table that controls where a given value can be used, and that will allow you to have sane drop down lists, but that isn't as good as referential integrity. If other tables need to relate to a lookup, you have to relate against this entire table, which is much less clear. You will have to be careful to enforce your own layer of referential integrity since the database can't help you. Finally, and this is a big deal, if any if your 143 values has or will ever have extra complexity and could really benefit from an additional column, cognitive load begins to escalate. If five of the 143 need their own columns, you now have to hold all five columns in your mind to understand any one column... That is agony. Here's a thought experiment for you if I'm not getting my point across: *why not build your entire project as one giant table?*
3. **143 tables:** The most flexible approach, and all things considered, the easiest to maintain by a massive margin. It does not close any doors; down the road you can still create a UI for editing any value you want. If you want to relate other tables to a lookup value, that relationship will be easy to understand because you can relate to LegalStatus instead of GiantEverythingTable, and enjoy the benefits of referential integrity, never having to worry about corrupting your own data. You can also script table and index creation with something like NimbleText (a great tool and a hidden gem). There will be a huge number of tables, which is itself a minor maintenance problem, but it's one that doesn't actually break anything and doesn't lead to cognitive load. This is an acceptable trade-off. I would go this way and generate enums using t4.

The thing about most software projects of any size is that you may look at my objections and say they don't apply, and you might be right. But if this thing is going to be in active development, you have to ask: are you sure? Do you really know what's going to happen in a year?

When considering trade-offs, I've learned to assign a lot of weight to the most flexible/simple decision. Maintainability problems are what kill software projects. They are the enemy.

Hope that helps!

Comment: using t4 with the 3rd approach may break version controlling due to sync issues between db and the codebase.

Comment: Hmm I suppose it depends on how you use it, and what kind of complexity you may have. I should say: in my case I tend to only use the generated enums when writing logic, I do not rely on them as a replacement for accessing the database. For instance I might say: if (LegalStatus.Bankrupt) { ... } which is just cleaner than saying if (65) { ... } ... However if I needed to fill a dropdownlist, I would hit the database. Also I do not automatically generate the t4 templates, I run them manually when appropriate. Which is generally any time I change those lookup tables.

Comment: ... I suppose for a really heavyweight dev ops scenario with lots of devs and branches, you might need more databases... Yes that could become tricky.

Comment: Thanks! I think I will go with a mix of 1 and 3 though. Find the fixed values which aren't going to be changed like a list of country's, colors, client type's and use those as a c# enum. Only the variabele lists I will put in a lookup table.. Is this feasible?

Comment: @Jesse It's feasible, but you do lose referential integrity and the ability to ever relate on those data points. Feels risky to me, like you are undermining your foundation. By moving that into an enum, you are "hiding the bodies" - the complexity is still there, in fact your problems may increase,  and your main win is that you don't have to look at 143 tables all the time.

Comment: @Jesse Also, enums can't contain characters like spaces, so you are going to have some weird looking drop down lists unless you do some extra work and find a solution to that :)

Comment: @ Brian MacKay I don't exactly get what you mean. What do I exactly lose if I put my languages in a c# enum? It gets stored as an integer by EF core... I don't see the problem?

For the spaces and characters: the enum is English only and will be a translation key (unique) which then will be translated in the frontend. So no worries there. 

For data that holds more than a key/value and extra data I will go for a lookup table anyways since that's not possible in enum as well

Comment: @Jesse re: referential integrity, you lose a few things. With referential integrity, the database enforces that if you put a 2 in Languages, there is a corresponding value with 2 in the Languages lookup table. If you ever try to delete 2 from the lookup table, it can stop that operation for you, etc. This may not be a big deal now, but lets say in a few years Languages has to be used in more tables. Now your situation is more complex and it's good that an entire class of bugs where broken values can accidentally be entered into tables is eliminated. Less worry about data sanitation, etc.

Comment: @Jesse I suppose I have learned to expect unexpected complexity, so I choose flexibility and maintainability whenever it's reasonably possible. :)